# Validate value 0 and range based validation in Lumen

Tags: php, validation, laravel, lumen

I want to perform following validation on my textfield using Lumen Validation:

**The value must be greater than 0 and less than or equal to 100**

My current code is:

```
$validator = Validator::make($params, [
          'weight' => 'required'        
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {

        $messages = $validator->errors();
        $message   = $messages->first();

        return  $message;    
        exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `between` validation rule to check this. The parameters are inclusive.

You also need to add in the `numeric` validation rule so that `between` will know to check if the numeric value is between the supplied values. Without the `numeric` validation, it would validate the length of the string, not the numeric value of it.

```
$validator = Validator::make($params, [
      'weight' => 'required|numeric|between:1,100'
]);
```

Comment: Great. What if I want to check the field must not be 0. its should be greater than 0

Comment: @NewCo The given validation should handle that. That is why the minimum value specified is 1, not 0.

Comment: Actully what if I want to remove the max range. So it should be greater than 0 only. I mean no upper limit

Comment: @NewCo In that case, you can use the `min` validation (also inclusive): `'weight' => 'required|numeric|min:1'`

Comment: @NewCo Documentation for validation rules is [here](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/validation).

Comment: what if the value is 0.01?

Comment: @NewCo Then you'll get a validation error message stating that "The weight must be at least 1.".

Comment: @NewCo If you want '0.01' to be valid, you could use the following rule: `'weight' => 'required|numeric|min:0|not_in:0'`.

Comment: @NewCo Your last comment belongs to your other question.